# vSphere Enhanced Authentication Plugin for SSO

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have recently configured a vCenter Server to monitor our companies virtual machines, and would like to use the Windows Sessionauthentication.
The vCenter is already joined to the AD Domain, and i can log in with my domain credentials no problem, but in order to use the Windows Session Authentication feature i need to download the "Enhanced Authentication Plugin", whenever i try to do so i get a certificate warning. so i figured i would go to the base URL of the vCenter Virtual appliance and click "Download trusted root CA certificates", when i do so i get taken to the proper URL (https://vcenter.domain.com/certs/download.zip) however no file gets downloaded, all i get is half a screen full of strange symbols.
Has anyone here ever had the same issue, and if so knows how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this iks an old topic but maybe the answer will assist someone else.  instead of clicking on the link, right click and save link as then browse to the save location you want and save it.  open the zip file and save the crt files.  (there will also be crl files) this should resolve the issue.